# opening database in raw folder & perform different read operation on it

Tags: android, sqlite

**Title**-Android-read database in raw folder..

My raw folder contains a database 'abc' & abc database contains one table say- xyz
i want to open 'abc' database for fetching data in it..

i want to use something like

SQLiteDatabase db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, factory, flags);

1) how to give path to access database?

2) i want to open table & perform operation
Cursor c=db.query("xyz",null,null,null,null,null);

Answer (score 0):

> Raw has no path: It is a resource, so you need to reference is as such
>   using getResources().
>
> You should, at the first run, copy it to the
>   /data/data/YOUR_APP_FOLDER/databases/YOUR_DB.db
>
> Follow this tutorial.
>
> http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: @user1461473. you get any method for this??

Answer (score 0):

Copy your database file from `/res/raw` or `/asset` in `/data/data/<application_package_name>/database/` directory and give path of that directory.

Now you can easily access your database file from /data/data//database/ directory..

Look at [Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Comment: its true but i want to access database from only raw or asset folder without changing its location.. is it possible???